# How is reputation for the day calculated?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I deleted some posts that have down votes. Will reputation from these posts be considered when calculating the reputation for that day?

Will the upvotes/downvotes on deleted posts be considered regarding the 200 reputation mark (to get Legendary badge) for that day?

Answer (score 1):

When the recalculation happens, you will get that reputation back from the deleted posts (as if they never happened). If you want, you can manually trigger a recalculation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: There is no need to manually recalc any more. Changes in reputation should be done automatically within a few minutes of the change occuring.

Comment: I have updated my post to make more clear what I want to know.

Comment: @Romil - You don't need to trigger the manual recalculation anymore, but the [audit page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) Oleksi linked does tell you at the bottom "earned at least 200 reputation on x days"